# SQL Linked tables by earlier date for each record

Tags: sql

It is not easy to describe my question. `Task` has different subtasks on different time frame. Base on each task record's (`Task` table) date to get the earlier subtask list from subtask table.

- `Task` table has columns `T1Date`, `T1Task`
- `Subtask` table has columns `T2Task`, `T2SubTask`, `T2Date`
- `Table2.T2Task` links to `Table1.T1Task`

`Table2` lists all subtasks for each task and effective date for each subtask.

For example:

Table1 records:

```
01/17/2015, Task1
02/24/2015, Task1
03/01/2015, Task2
05/01/2015, Task2
```

Total four tasks have been executed in different date.

Table2 records:

```
Task1, SubTask1_1, 01/15/2015
Task1, SubTask1_2, 01/15/2015
Task1, SubTask1_3, 01/15/2015
Task1, SubTask1_1, 02/15/2015
Task1, SubTask1_4, 02/15/2015
Task2, SubTask2_1, 01/01/2015
Task2, SubTask2_2, 04/01/2015
Task2, SubTask2_3, 07/01/2015
```

It means `Task1` carries subtask 1_1, 1_2 and 1_3 if it happens between 01/15/2015 to 02/14/2015. And Task1 change to subtask 1_1 and 1_4 from 02/15/2015 and after

I need SQL results:

```
01/17/2015, Task1, SubTask1_1, 01/15/2015
01/17/2015, Task1, SubTask1_2, 01/15/2015
01/17/2015, Task1, SubTask1_3, 01/15/2015
02/24/2015, Task1, SubTask1_1, 02/15/2015
02/24/2015, Task1, SubTask1_4, 02/15/2015
03/01/2015, Task2, SubTask2_1, 01/01/2015
05/01/2015, Task2, SubTask2_2, 04/01/2015
```

I can use below SQL to get the latest result with hardcode date.  But, I do not know how to use reach record's T1Date to replace #2/1/2015# on the SQL below.

```
SELECT 
    T1Date, T1Task, T2SubTask, T2Date 
FROM 
    Table1 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         Table2.T2Task, Table2.T2subTask, MAX(Table2.T2Date) as maxdate 
     FROM 
         Table2 
     WHERE 
         Table2.T2Date <= #2/1/2015# 
     GROUP by 
         T2subtask) AS b ON Table1.T1Task = b.T2Task AND Table2.Date = b.maxdate
```

Comment: It's `n-n` relation !!! It's the worst thing you can do in relational database.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQLServer 2012 or higher, you can use the ROWS argument to the OVER windowing function to get the previous date from Table1, creating a range of dates the T2 dates should fall into:

```
;WITH Table1WithPriorDate AS (
    SELECT  T1Task
    ,       T1Date
    ,       MIN(T1Date) OVER (
                PARTITION BY T1Task
                ORDER BY T1Date
                ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
            ) AS PriorDate
    FROM    Table1
), T1Tasks AS (
    SELECT  T1Task
    ,       T1Date
    ,       CASE PriorDate
            WHEN T1Date THEN 'January 1, 1753'
            ELSE PriorDate
            END AS PriorDate
    FROM    Table1WithPriorDate
)
SELECT  T1Task
,       T1Date
,       PriorDate
,       ISNULL( T2Task, 'null' ) AS T2Task
,       ISNULL( T2SubTask, 'null' ) AS T2SubTask
,       ISNULL( T2Date, DATEADD(YEAR,100,GETDATE()) ) AS T2Date
FROM    T1Tasks AS T1
LEFT JOIN   Table2 AS T2
    ON  T2.T2Task = T1.T1Task
    AND T2.T2Date BETWEEN PriorDate AND T1Date
```

SQLFiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5a2b6/59

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have SQL Server 2012 or later, you can use a correlated subquery in the select to ascertain the prior date for each task

```
;WITH T1Tasks AS (
    SELECT t.*
    ,      ISNULL((SELECT MAX(p.T1Date) FROM Table1 AS p WHERE p.T1Task = t.T1Task AND p.T1Date < t.T1Date),'January 1, 1753') AS PriorDate
    FROM   Table1 AS t
)
SELECT  T1Task
,       T1Date
,       PriorDate
,       ISNULL( T2Task, 'null' ) AS T2Task
,       ISNULL( T2SubTask, 'null' ) AS T2SubTask
,       ISNULL( T2Date, DATEADD(YEAR,100,GETDATE()) ) AS T2Date
FROM    T1Tasks AS T1
LEFT JOIN   Table2 AS T2
    ON  T2.T2Task = T1.T1Task
    AND T2.T2Date BETWEEN PriorDate AND T1Date
```

SQLFiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5a2b6/66/0